# Latest status on stability of CNN architectures to noise and "clever hans" issues

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-segmentation, stability

I was working with CNN architectures for image segmentation a few years ago, and I remember there was a big concern about on the stability of the predicted masks due to the introduction of small amounts of noise. If just a little gaussian noise was added to the image, then the predicted mask might change in important ways--generally around the margins.

Similar issues arose in classification problems, where MRI images were being classified based upon external queues within the images, and not based upon the images themselves--the "clever hans" problem as it is called. For example, sometimes the training images hospital labels that implicitly meant that an image was "positive" for some illness. Hence the CNN was using the label for detection instead of the data contained in the image. Here is a [link to a 2022 paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1361841522000214) that discusses the continuing challenge of Clever Hans problems in MRI images. There were also issues where the CNN classification of images did not generalize beyond the specific machines that the training images came from.

I was just wondering what the current status of these stability issues was within CNN architectures, or probably across Deep Learning architectures. In particular, are there any new architectural changes to help CNNs or deep learning architectures overcome these issues? Are there newer training methods, etc. For example, do contrastive learning methods improve on the stability of CNN predictions, etc. I am most interested in medical imaging, but input from any topical area is welcome.